# Can anybody recommend a 'good' book to learn about black holes?

Tags: time, black-hole

I am really interested in learning about black holes, and tbh I know absolutely nothing about them. But I am really eager to learn about them. So I'm searching for books that can teach me in easy comprehensible english.

Comment: This is a physics/astronomy question. The people here speak celestial mechanics and spacecraft technology, but natural phenomena like black holes, interesting as they are, aren't in the scope of this SE community, I don't think...

Comment: Stephen Hawking had very popular books on the subject for a lay audience, though nowadays I'm sure a few other names have taken his place as subject matter experts... For mathematical expositions, I would maybe search MIT OpenCourseware syllabi for the textbooks they use.

Comment: You asked this question in the wrong part of StackExchange. You should ask it in another part of StackExhange, for example Physics or Astronomy. This is Space Exploration, here. Good luck. Your question here is likely to be closed before long, which means no one will be able to post Answers to it. By the way, when you write 'good' in quotes like that, you make the meaning into a strange one: a book that is said to be good, or is supposedly good, but that is not necessarily good. Anyway, to find such books, try a bookshop or library.